# SQL Server 2008 setup failure: Value cannot be null. Parameter name : doc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-handling

I am trying to add some services (Full-Text search, Integration services etc) to SQL Server 2008 that I didn't install with the first installation of sql server, now when I choose to add those features to sql server I'm getting an error message:

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name : doc.

I have Win 7 x64

[image]
[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Sill but try SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Kosanag did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

seen this issue on another forum, the user claims repairing microsoft .net 4.0 solves the issue.

note: another user claims using a local account on the machine solved the installation problem, and then re-loggin on the other account makes the issue solved also on this other account

Answer (score -3):

Right click on the .exe and "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Didn't work, is there any other ways

Comment: Didn't work, Same error in SQL Server 2014  is there any other solution?